# (playStore/Android)Transfer owner permission of deleted account to another

Tags: android, google-play, account

we are having a problem with our playstore(android).

The owner account of Play Store was deleted after the one who launched our app left company.
The account was created via G-suite(company account).

The account with owner permissions was deleted, which is why we are having issues.

We would like to transfer the owner account permissions to another account by proving that the company owns the app. We tried transferring owner permission, but we could not do that because we cannot access deleted account.

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with this, getting the owner permissions back from a deleted account.

Thank you for your help.

1. Contact the Korean Play Store to see if they can resolve the issue.
2. Try creating an email with the same name in G suite

Comment: play store support are the only people who can help with such issues. How would you transfer the ownership of a deleted account?